# helloword cocos2d-x android fail

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I'm student and with my classmates, we have to realize a game for Android and IOS.
We use the cocos2d-x framework to do so but we have a problem with the execution of the android's helloword project.
In fact we can see the helloword application on the android simulator but when we launch it we have a black screen and we can't do nothing.
We can launch the win32 application without problems but it's the android part that crash appart.
I thank you in advance and i apologize for my bad english because i'm not english or american.

Comment: not clear enough, if you post your environment with more details will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Android old Emulator doesnt support OpenGl even if they support they are too laggy .. So you need to test it on devices ....

If you are using the latest version of Cocos2d-x which utilizes OpenGL ES 2.0 it will not work under the emulator. The emulator does not support OpenGL ES 2.0. In addition using an emulator when shows its too laggy ... so test it on device better option

Even though if you are interested in running it on emulator

you have to add this line in manifest
< uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />